# How can I make a code that count the printed repots per day?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I need to export a PDF file with sequential name:

"year"+"month"+"day"+"printed repots per day"

Ex.: 20200130_035

I made the date code.

```
Dim strArquivo As String
Dim strLocal As String

strArquivo = "" & Year(Date) & Month(Date) & Day(Date) & HERE THE REPORTS PRINTED QUANTITY & " .pdf "
strLocal = CurrentProject.Path & "\PDF\" & strArquivo
DoCmd.OutputTo acReport, "Report", acFormatPDF, strLocal
```

How can I make a code that count the printed repots per day?

Comment: Where do you keep a record of the number of printed reports per day?

Comment: That is my question. How can I do that?

Comment: Store it in a table and update it with +1, or insert name of pdf with primary key of auto increment.

Answer (score 0):

Matheus,

I've put together some code that seems to work, together with some comments.

I would suggest that you format the date to be a consistent length (such as "ddmmyy" or "yymmdd"), otherwise 11 January and 1 November will both appear as "111";

I would also suggest both separating and formatting the report number, such as "-001"/"-002" to make things clearer;

You may want to also store the report name when you PDF the reports.

```
Dim strLocal As String
Dim intCount As Integer
strLocal = Format(Date, "yymmdd")
intCount = Nz(DCount("PrintDate", "tblPrintID", "PrintDate='" & Format(Date, "yymmdd") & "'"), 0) + 1
strLocal = "C:\test\" & strLocal & "-" & Format(intCount,"000") & ".pdf"
Debug.Print strLocal
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "rpt1", acFormatPDF, strLocal
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tblPrintID (PrintDate,PrintReport) SELECT '" & Format(Date, "yymmdd") & "','rpt1';"
```

Regards